# validation errors W3c

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, magento-1.9

I am getting the error

**Parse Error progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#cc000000', GradientType=0) }**

here is the code

```
.surgeryCategory .card-title.gradient {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#cc000000', GradientType=0)
}
```

Comment: Which version of IE browser are you using? I have tested your code with a div, there is no error display in IE browser (IE8+). Besides, with reference to the [MDN -ms-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-filter) and [Microsoft Gradient Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/ms532997(v%3Dvs.85)), we can see that the gradient Filter is deprecated as of Windows Internet Explorer 9. As of Internet Explorer 10 this feature was removed and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to put semicolon at the end of the line

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#cc000000', GradientType=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct code. You forgot to add semicolon at the end of the second last line.

```css
.surgeryCategory .card-title.gradient {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(125, 185, 232, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007db9e8', endColorstr='#cc000000', GradientType=0);
}
```